# Suppress NA column when faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my plot faceting occurs by two columns:

```
ggplot(peakDF, aes (Mass, Intensity)) + geom_line()+ facet_grid(file ~ fragment, scales = "free")
```

in the fragment column I have a lot of NA values so a column of plots is produced with these NAs as shown below:

[image]

the problem is I don't want this column, but I can't simply filter on NA values in this column, because this would remove normalisation (across rows) which I really need. Any suggestions on how to preserve the whole dataset (for normalisation), yet not to plot the NA column?

Comment: what do you mean for normalization? leave out the scales=free or just set to free_x?

Comment: I mean I want the plots in the facet windows to be plotted with maximum on y axis as the maximum in the correponding row, including values are under NA column in the facet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to do this exactly without your data, but one option would be to convert to a `gtable` object and then just trim off that extra column you don't want.

My sample code will use R's built in `mtcars`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
p<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, hp)) + geom_point()+ facet_grid(cyl ~ carb, scales = "free")
gt<-ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
```

**Without Trim**

```
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

**With Trim**

```
gt2<-gt[,-14]
grid.draw(gt2)
```

[image]

You can see that with trimming we simply took off the last column that we don't want (column 14, which had the 8 cyl plot in it). To figure out which column you want to trim you can do:

```
gtable_show_layout(gt)
```

Using this you can match the specific facets of your plot with the columns in `gtable` that you want to remove.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a fake data set to control the limits. This should be easy in your case--just calculate the max for `Intensity` by `file`. Or you can input custom limits like below

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e3
peakDF <- data.frame(Mass = rnorm(n, 500, 50),
                     Intensity = runif(n, 0, 10),
                     file = sample(letters[1:4], n, TRUE),
                     fragment = sample(letters[1:6], n, TRUE))
peakDF$fragment[1:(n/2)] <- NA
```

what you have now

```
ggplot(peakDF, aes (Mass, Intensity)) +
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(file ~ fragment, scales = "free")
```

[image]

with `na.omit` and changing the upper limit for `file=='a'`

```
ggplot(na.omit(peakDF), aes (Mass, Intensity)) +
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(file ~ fragment, scales = "free") +
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(Mass = Inf,
                               fragment = 'a',
                               file = 'a',
                               Intensity = 15))
```

[image]

You can add multiple controls at the same time. In your case you could just get the max value for the `NA`s by file and use that summary data frame

```
ggplot(na.omit(peakDF), aes (Mass, Intensity)) +
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(Mass = rep(Inf, 4),
                               fragment = rep('a', 4),
                               file = c('a', 'a', 'c', 'd'),
                               Intensity = c(15, -5, 50, -5))) +
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(file ~ fragment, scales = "free")
```

[image]

This would also work for the x-axis or both the x- and y.